# eventlistener with element.on on <video> in a angular directive doesn't trigger

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I use something like this in a directives link function:

```
var vdo = element.find('video')[0];
vdo.on('loadstart', function () {
   console.log('onloadstart');
});
```

The code isn't executed. Instead I have to use:

```
vdo.onloadstart = function() {
  console.log('onloadstart');
};
```

or

```
vdo.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
  console.log('onloadstart');
});
```

Can someone explain me why? And is it a problem to use `addEventListener` at all?

Comment: how do you trigger `loadstart`?

Comment: set the source in controller <video ng-src="{{source}}" controls></video>

Comment: do you trigger `loadstart` manually on `<video>`?

Comment: What do you mean? I set the source and this trigers a loadstart. Anyway, no event is triggered with "on"...

Answer (score 1):

The *angular way* would be a custom directive:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.src = 'w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
      alert('loadstart!');
    };
}

myApp.directive('onLoad', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      func: '&onLoad'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('loadstart', function() {
        scope.func();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <video controls on-load="myFunc()">
    <source ng-src="{{src}}">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah. You could also do it like this. Nice. By the way, but how do you execute a parent function with &-attrib binding?
Anyway, this answers not my question, because your code doesn't get executed also!

Comment: Nope. You cannot create two isolated scopes on an element. My directive also needs an isolated scope. But I'm repeating, this solves NOT my problem...

Comment: Well, why don't you post all of your code then or - even better - create a fiddle which shows your problem.

Comment: Did you try your code? Does it run/work? No! I have posted all the necessary stuff. Please read my question...

Comment: I tried my post and it works. For you, I even put it right into here to show you that it works. You are welcome.  P.S.: nice how you treat people that try to help you.